# Does Istio on GKE creates different service account for each service for mutual TLS

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

To enable Mutual TLS, every service in service mesh needs to have different identity and client certificates.

Does Istio on GKE creates different service account for each service for mutual TLS?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. More information can be viewed [here](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/).

By default Istio on GKE will not create different/multiple service accounts for each service that has a mutual TLS enabled. When a Citadel instance notices that a ServiceAccount is created in a namespace, it must decide whether it should generate an istio.io/key-and-cert secret for that ServiceAccount. You just need to check that there is a secret assigned to the service account.

Under the section [How Citadel determines whether to create Service Account secrets](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#how-citadel-determines-whether-to-create-service-account-secrets) there is a table that will show you the decision making process.

Additionally, in the section [Mutual TLS authentication](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#mutual-tls-authentication) you will see the step-by-step process for a client to call a server with mTLS.

Comment: What is meant by "When a Citadel instance notices that a ServiceAccount is created in a namespace"? There could be multiple services in a namespace. If I get it right, there could be services without service accounts, and for them no client certificate will be created? How would then mutual TLS works, without identity of a service?

Comment: When you install Istio, with it comes Citadel by default and a service account. Citadel enables service-to-service and end-user authentication with built-in identity and credential management. You just need to make sure that specific service account in the services has a secret assigned to it. That service account is created in a namespace where there can be multiple services. Essentially, the same service account can be used for multiple services for mTLS.

Comment: Although same service account is used for multiple services, but every service gets different identity and different certificates?